# Moderator dashboard broken for employees without meta accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

On [SR's dashboard](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/admin?filter=all) (SR mods / employees only), one of the employees that has handled a flag or two doesn't have an account on meta. On their row, the meta posts and meta comments columns don't exist. It looks like the cells for those are skipped entirely, leaving all the other stats out of line with the headers.

This is hard to read, can we please show `--` or something when a cell has no value?

Comment: Looks like it's also busted the javascript on the page - fixing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just defaulted the missing data to zeros; going out in the next build.